# Loading Tomcat Resource in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Within my server.xml I have something like the following line:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
<Resource factory="com.company.ServerEnvironmentFactory" name="config/ServerEnvironment" type="java.util.Map"/>
```

Within Spring 3, how to do ensure that the ServerEnvironmentFactory is created, such that I can do a Context lookup for java:/comp/env/config/ServerEnvironment.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to configure your context.xml so that all Application are aware of the global resource.

```
<ResourceLink global="config/ServerEnvironment" name="config/ServerEnvironment" type="java.util.Map" />
```

Comment: That's probably true. I have my contextConfigLocation defined as jpaContext.xml. So I'm guessing I need to edit that, I just don't know what that line would look like.

Comment: Sorry, you meant the tomcat context.xml. I tried that, but I'm still getting javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [config/ServerEnvironment] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [config].

Comment: @Quirk ... modified the answer, added global attribute. Try to add it restart Tomcat to see if it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. I think it's my Spring project that's missing a configuration settings somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<bean id="myEnv" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/comp/env/config/ServerEnvironment"/>
</bean>
```

Resources:

[Tomcat Java JNDI Example](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

[Spring JNDI Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html)

Comment: I agree with this, but I'm also using a custom resource factory, I'm getting:  Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [config/ServerEnvironment] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [config].

Comment: Is the resource factory accessable from Tomcats classpath? for example in a jar in tomcat/lib/ or tomcat/common/lib? Otherwise Tomcat can access and use it.